# on click change the class for current nav-link not all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have bootstrap tab and the content will display when click on respective menu tabs

I want when click on the particular menu the customize class should active withat that menu not every menu tabs.

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">...</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    //function of collapse and tabpen   
    $(document).on('click','.nav-link.active', function(){
      var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
    //alert(href);
      $('.tab-pane[id="'+ href +'"]').toggleClass('active');

    });
    $('.nav-link').click(function(){
     $('this').addClass('addplus');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of two different codes there, in single code every-thing will work:-

```
$('.nav-link').click(function(){
 $('.nav-link').removeClass('addplus active');//first remove classes from previous nav link
 $(this).addClass('addplus active'); //remove '' around this
 var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
 $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
 $('.tab-pane[id="'+ href +'"]').toggleClass('active');
});
```

A demo example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav-link').click(function(){
    $('.nav-link').removeClass('addplus active');
    $(this).addClass('addplus active');
    var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
    $('.tab-pane[id="'+ href +'"]').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:green;
  font-size:20px;
}

.addplus{
  font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="home" role="tabpanel">home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">messages</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">settings</div>
</div>
```

Note:-

I recreated your `//function of collapse and tabpen` function so that it will work too. You can check in example.Thanks

Comment: Thanks.I want at first the colors should remain black when click then it would be green both the menu and its content and when click again on green it should be black

Comment: @Tanmay  you need to do that much at your end. remove active class from html initially

Comment: actually this is where i'm facing tthe problem everything is perfect  but when i try to click green text again then it do not chnages to black.
aND thanks :)

Comment: @Tanmay  glad to help you :):)

Comment: can you p;ease tell me the way to click the green to make it black again

Comment: @Tanmay  please ask a new question regarding that with proper input and your code effort+ clear description about what you want actually. You will get answer for sure. You can address me the link and if i have time i will answer for-sure